# How to await Uint8List bytes inside a widget to create a memory image Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i'm trying to generate a memory image from a base64 string, but my problem is that the widget goes into an error because the "Uint8List bytes" is empty for a few seconds before the image is loaded:

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
> The getter 'length' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: length

a few seconds later the widget shows the image and the red screen is gone.

how i do to wait that  the Uint8List bytes is complete before draw the widget? i try to use await but i can't use this inside the widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Uint8List bytes = ***await*** base64Decode(_base64);
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'My image',
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('My image'),
    ),
    body: Container(
    width: 130,
    height: 130,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child:   Image.memory(bytes, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
  ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
  future: base64Decode(_base64),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);

    Uint8List bytes = snapshot.data;
    return Image.memory(bytes, fit: BoxFit.fill,);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by telling the build function to draw nothing while `bytes` is not defined. That would look something like:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Uint8List bytes = ***await*** base64Decode(_base64);
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'My image',
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('My image'),
    ),
    body: Container(
    width: 130,
    height: 130,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child: bytes != null ? Image.memory(bytes, fit: BoxFit.fill,) : Container(),
  ),
  ),
);
```

In which case an empty container is shown while bytes is null, and the image is shown otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Future builder : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

So you can put a spinner while you image is loading, and when it's done, display your image.